# Error using rioXarray in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, raster, rasterio

Am trying to follow Earth Lab Earth analytics python courses. Where theres recent changes from using RasterIO to RioXArray.
I am using the exact same data provided from the tutorials which works perfectly with RasterIO, however when trying to open the same data with the exact method instructed on the tutorial, it fails and gave errors related to setting wrong variables

```
rioxarray.open_rasterio(datapath)
```

Link to [tutorial](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/intro-raster-data-python/fundamentals-raster-data/open-lidar-raster-python-xarray/)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/common.py in **setattr**(self, name, value)
267         try:
--> 268             object.**setattr**(self, name, value)
269         except AttributeError as e:

AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute '_file_obj'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 rxr.open_rasterio(datapath)

~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rioxarray/_io.py in open_rasterio(filename, parse_coordinates, chunks, cache, lock, masked, mask_and_scale, variable, group, default_name, **open_kwargs)
866
867     # Make the file closeable
--> 868     result._file_obj = manager
869
870     return result

~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/common.py in **setattr**(self, name, value)
274             ):
275                 raise
--> 276             raise AttributeError(
277                 "cannot set attribute %r on a %r object. Use **setitem** style"
278                 "assignment (e.g., `ds['name'] = ...`) instead of assigning variables."

AttributeError: cannot set attribute '_file_obj' on a 'DataArray' object. Use **setitem** styleassignment (e.g., `ds['name'] = ...`) instead of assigning variables.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDsFJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to changes in xarray 0.17. rioxarray 0.3.1 has been updated to address this. See: https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/releases/tag/0.3.1